# how to check if a variable or command is from bash or unix?

Tags: bash, unix

In bash, one can use

```
env
printev
```

to print environment(global) variables, or use

```
set
```

to print local variables.
However, how could one know, if this variable is from bash scripting environment, or, from the unix operation system?

similar questions to the commands, how could one know

```
ls
grep
od
```

etc, is from the Ubuntu OS or from the bash environment?

Comment: Your first question does not make sense.  What do you mean for a variable to be "from the unix [operating] system"?

Comment: Oh!, so there's no operation system variables? sorry if i raised a stupid wrong question... in windows, there are some system variables such as PATH etc...

Comment: There are environment variables (such as PATH), but there's no difference between an environment variable that is set by the shell and one that is inherited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `type` builtin.

```
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ type ps
ps is /bin/ps
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ type type
type is a shell builtin
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ type if
if is a shell keyword
```

Comment: i suppose these are for commands: "ps is /bin/ps" means this is a "UNIX OS command"; "shell builtin" => "bash environment command"; "shell keyword" => "bash shell reserved keyword"? how about variables then? when i run "type $PS1" it shows "-bash: type: \t\s\e[0;34m\w\e[m\$: not found"; when i run "type $IFS", it shows nothing...

Comment: @athos Indeed, `type` cannot differentiate between environment variables and shell attributes.